# iphone daemon process

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to understand if there is any way to write a real daemon (or service) running under iOS 4.x.

Note that I understand that the official SDK does not allow for such things to be distributed on the AppStore, but what if I wanted, for example, to distribute my app using the "enterprise" program to a set of employees?

And no, I do not want to Jailbreak my employees' iphones.

Comment: You could make your app jailbreak the devices without anyone knowing, but this might be against local ethics. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer is 'sort of'. If you don't want to jailbreak phones, your options are rather limited. As long as you're only intending to distribute internally, you can look into the VOIP background services.

It's part of iOS 4's background services, and is intended to allow VOIP apps to run constantly in the background to pick up events such as incoming calls, etc. It is possible to use it to achieve other things, such as a regularly scheduled service (I think there was a recent question where somebody wanted to use it to act as a 'data counter', again for the enterprise program).

It's not really a 'correct' or proper solution, but it's the best you've got unless you want to jailbreak your phones - and it goes without saying it's unsuitable for apps to be distributed on the store.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much. But, I also need my app to startup automatically when the phone is restarted and I did not see a way to do it (I assume VOIP app need that function, but I could not find it). Anyway to get down to the OS level and run Unix commands to do that?

Comment: This is provided automatically with the VOIP background service. From Apple's docs for UIBackgroundModes: "applications with this key [voip] are automatically launched after system boot". I'm pretty convinced that's the best you can get from iOS unless you're prepared to jailbreak your devices.

Answer (score 1):

As part of its sandbox security, the stock iOS OS will kill any process which was started by other than the OS, or which isn't registered to run (such as having the proper background plist keys when in the background).  Unix commands to start a process won't work.

So the only currently supported way to do this on a stock OS device is with a VOIP app, or for private use, a faux VOIP app, if you want auto launch on reboot.  If you don't need launch on reboot, a background audio app that plays silence, or records to /dev/null, might also work.

Note that the user can kill these background apps very easily, and they won't be restarted until another reboot or manual launch.