# iOS location services on terminated app

Tags: ios, mobile, gps

I am trying to create a GPS location app that will monitor and send the location to a server. I want the location service to be able to continue to run even after the app is terminated/killed(not just in the background).

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this, but your options are very limited

- Your app won't be able to be in the store:

> 2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

- It might get kill on background

> Save user data and app state information. All unsaved changes should be written to disk when entering the background. This step is necessary because your app might be quietly killed while in the background for any number of reasons. You can perform this operation from a background thread as needed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

But if you still want to do this, check this out:

> I guess the answer is 'sort of'. If you don't want to jailbreak phones, your options are rather limited. As long as you're only intending to distribute internally, you can look into the VOIP background services.
>
> It's part of iOS 4's background services, and is intended to allow VOIP apps to run constantly in the background to pick up events such as incoming calls, etc. It is possible to use it to achieve other things, such as a regularly scheduled service (I think there was a recent question where somebody wanted to use it to act as a 'data counter', again for the enterprise program).

From Here: [iphone daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640261/iphone-daemon-process)